# Two-stage templated alias not resolvable in constructor?

Tags: templates, alias

I am trying to work with a two-stage templated alias, but I cannot get the alias to be accepted as a constructor parameter.  Is there a way to do this?

An example of what I am trying to do is seen in the following code:

```
#include <memory>

template <typename Bar>
class Foo
{
public:
   using FooPtr = std::shared_ptr<Foo<Bar> >;

   static FooPtr getFooPtr(Bar someBar) { return std::make_shared<Foo<Bar> >(someBar); }
   Foo(Bar bar) : _bar(bar) {}

   Bar getBar() { return _bar; }

private:
   Bar _bar;
};

template <typename Bar>
class Foobar
{
public:
    using FB = Foo<Bar>;
    Foobar(FB::FooPtr fooPtr)
       : _fooPtr(fooPtr)
    {
    }

    FB::FooPtr getFooPtr() { return _fooPtr; }

private:
    FB::FooPtr _fooPtr;
};

int main()
{
   Foobar myFoobar<int>(f::getFooPtr(4));
   return myFoobar.getFooPtr()->getBar();
}
```

When I compile this with g++, I get the following:

```
dev@ubuntu:~/test/fsm$ g++ -std=c++1z test.cpp
test.cpp:23:23: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘fooPtr’
     Foobar(FB::FooPtr fooPtr)
                       ^
test.cpp:28:5: error: need ‘typename’ before ‘Foobar<Bar>::FB::FooPtr’ because ‘Foobar<Bar>::FB’ is a dependent scope
     FB::FooPtr getFooPtr() { return _fooPtr; }
     ^
test.cpp:31:5: error: need ‘typename’ before ‘Foobar<Bar>::FB::FooPtr’ because ‘Foobar<Bar>::FB’ is a dependent scope
     FB::FooPtr _fooPtr;
     ^
test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
test.cpp:36:11: error: missing template arguments before ‘myFoobar’
    Foobar myFoobar<int>(f::getFooPtr(4));
           ^
test.cpp:37:11: error: ‘myFoobar’ was not declared in this scope
    return myFoobar.getFooPtr()->getBar();
```

Is the compiler not recognizing the alias FB in the Foobar constuctor?  Or is it a problem with resolving Foo::FooPtr to a type?

Thanks!

Comment: The error message is clear: "error: need ‘typename’ before ‘Foobar<Bar>::FB::FooPtr’".  You have to add `typename` before `FB::FooPtr`

Comment: You are completely right.  I missed it because I was looking at the first error message (from line 23) which does not specify that 'typename' is missing.    Adding 'typename' does fix all the cases.  Thanks!